# Session flash not working in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

I have created a page, which when loaded moves the file from one folder to another on the ftp server. I want to flash a message when this is completed. But I am using Session::flash but it isn't working. Please check the code snippets and correct me if I am wrong. The file is moving properly.

test.blade.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{url('/ftp')}}',
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              console.log(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

TestController.php

```
function ftp()
{
  $ftp_server;
  $ftp_username;  
  $ftp_userpass; 
  $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
  // $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

  if (@ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass))
  {
    echo "Connection established.<br>";
    $path = "./test";
    $file = "ftp_test.txt";
    $file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,$path);

    if(in_array($file,$file_list))
    {
      $old_path="./test/ftp_test.txt.";
      $new_path="./test1/ftp_test.txt";
      if(ftp_rename($ftp_conn,$old_path,$new_path))
      {
        echo "File moved from $old_path to $new_path.<br>";
        Session::flash('success','File moved from a to b');
      }
      else {
        echo "File not moved.";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $old_path="./test1/ftp_test.txt.";
      $new_path="./test/ftp_test.txt";
      if(ftp_rename($ftp_conn,$old_path,$new_path))
      {
        echo "File moved from $old_path to $new_path.<br>";
        Session::flash('success','File moved from b to a');
      }
      else {
        echo "File not moved.";
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Couldn't establish a connection.<br>";
  }



  // close connection
  ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As you are using the ajax call session won't be working, handle the show message scenario with the jquery

Comment: @Kuru can you please help me on that.

Comment: If you are using AJAX then you don't need to set session, just echo the message and you will get that message in the response

Comment: @RajShah check the answer

Comment: Won't help you much with your problem but when using `Session::flash()` you need to redirect to another page afterwards and have code somewhere in your blade files to display the corresponding warning, notice, error etc.

Comment: Yes, I am displaying the session messages. I even used redirect()->back(). but still no messages.

Comment: `redirect()->back()->with('success','File moved from b to a');` use like this

Comment: not working. actually it is not redirecting, i think as the page isn't refreshing.

Comment: @if(Session::has('message'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif

Comment: @if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    {{ Session('success') }}</div>
    @endif

        using similar way.

Answer (score 0):

in blade:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{url('/ftp')}}',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#message').text(data);
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Controller

```
 function ftp()
{
  $ftp_server;
  $ftp_username;  
  $ftp_userpass; 
  $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
  // $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

  if (@ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass))
  {
    echo "Connection established.<br>";
    $path = "./test";
    $file = "ftp_test.txt";
    $file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,$path);

    if(in_array($file,$file_list))
    {
      $old_path="./test/ftp_test.txt.";
      $new_path="./test1/ftp_test.txt";
      if(ftp_rename($ftp_conn,$old_path,$new_path))
      {
        echo "File moved from $old_path to $new_path.<br>";

      }
      else {
        echo "File not moved.";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $old_path="./test1/ftp_test.txt.";
      $new_path="./test/ftp_test.txt";
      if(ftp_rename($ftp_conn,$old_path,$new_path))
      {
        echo "File moved from $old_path to $new_path.";

      }
      else {
        echo "File not moved.";
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Couldn't establish a connection.<br>";
  }



  // close connection
  ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}

}
```

What i have is just removed your session things. In your blade create an element with id named as `message` (where you want to show the message) then append it with the results. Note your results has to just text, as you echo in your php script, ajax will get those text output as the data and returned you. you can style your message element as you want.
If you plan on return as html data use `$('#message').html(data);` instead of `$('#message').text(data);`

Comment: I had done that earlier, but I want a flash message which the session flash does. I am using the same Session::flash() in other functions, there it is working correctly. 

Check the below code it is from a different controller. ajaxcontroller.php , this also returns the value to ajax call and is working fine.

  else {
   $data['message']=1;
   Session::flash('error', 'The Phone Number Already Exsits.');

Answer (score 0):

As @kerbholz said, if you need to show a message just with a Session::flash you can't use **ajax**
Here is how you can show a flash message

#### In your controller

```
Session::flash('success', 'It\'s a flash message !');
return redirect()->back();
```

#### In your blade view

```
@if (Session::has('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>

@endif
```